# what is the difference between a node and a client in the ethereum context?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I'am new to ethereum, I canno't find the difference between a client and a node.
I concider the client to be an mplementation of the node in a programming language such as go or js?

Answer (score 1):

These terms are used interchangeably and often mixed. It depends if the text discuss about a client (node) connecting to Ethereum P2P network or if the text discussed about a client (JSON-RPC API client) connecting to a node providing API services.